# Error messages in Eclipse with the Android Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When I eclipse, I get a whole bunch of error messages on the log about a missing "Bundle file URL". Nothing is obviously broken as far as I can tell, but dozens of error messages in the log everytime I open up an Android project seems like it could indicate a problem.

The messages seem to be triggered when I open a layout XML file.

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.600
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/IViewRule.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.618
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/String.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.624
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/Map.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.639
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/INode.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.642
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/MenuAction.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.645
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/List.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.659
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/IMenuCallback.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.662
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/MenuAction.Action.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.679
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/Boolean.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.682
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/INodeHandler.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.686
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/Set.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.702
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/MenuAction.Choices.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.719
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/MenuAction.Group.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.725
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/IAttributeInfo.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.746
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/IGraphics.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.760
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/Rect.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.762
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/DrawingStyle.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.767
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/IDragElement.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.780
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/DropFeedback.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.784
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/Point.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:17.814
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/_rules_engine.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:18.083
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/ANDROID_URI.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:18.101
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/ATTR_ID.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:18.125
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/Closure.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:18.143
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/ATTR_TEXT.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:18.565
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/AndroidViewViewRuleBeanInfo.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 19:52:18.567
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/BaseViewBeanInfo.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.518
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/INode.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.520
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/IDragElement.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.522
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/DropFeedback.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.562
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/AndroidWidgetTimePickerRuleBeanInfo.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.564
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/IgnoredLayoutRuleBeanInfo.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.566
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/BaseLayoutBeanInfo.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.830
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/String.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.833
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/INode.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.835
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/MenuAction.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.837
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/List.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.840
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/ANDROID_URI.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.854
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/IMenuCallback.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.856
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/MenuAction.Action.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.860
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/Boolean.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.863
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/INodeHandler.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.866
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/MenuAction.Choices.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.871
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/IDragElement.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.873
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/DropFeedback.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.877
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/IFeedbackPainter.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.880
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/IGraphics.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.882
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/Rect.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.884
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/DrawingStyle.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.892
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/Point.groovy'

!    ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:45.894
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/Integer.groovy'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2010-12-24 20:39:46.023
!MESSAGE Bundle file URL not found at path '/gscripts/AndroidWidgetLinearLayoutRuleBeanInfo.groovy'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely ignore those messages. They were documenting a search for applicable rule-files for the current selection -- and these search messages should NOT have been showing up in the error log.  And in the latest release (which is not yet finished, but you can get preview snapshots at tools.android.com) they are completely gone (and the search algorithm has completely changed; we don't rely on groovy scripts for this anymore.)

(I work on the ADT)

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Project -> Clean` and then clean your project.

From my experience, Android plugin for Eclipse ocassionaly has false warnings, and this way works for eliminating them.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did try that, and also made sure that everything was updated to the latest versions, for good measure.  I still get the message.  It seems to spew out all the messages everytime I open a layout XML, but not java files or other types of XML files.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me recently. The UI editor is trying to instantiate a control and that control is throwing an exception somewhere in its constructor.

If this xml layout is a custom control you created, try to debug it by just commenting out some lines until you find the culprit. In my case I was trying to load shared preferences in the constructor of a custom control that was throwing an exception only in the designer. I added a try catch around that to fix it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's not a custom control, just a layout using plain old android views and layouts.  I'm also not sure I understand the second paragraph... what did you add a try/catch block around?  I'm getting this error in the eclipse error log when I open an XML layout file.